# 2D array of chars to 1D array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

what is the easiest way to copy a two-dimensional array of chars into a one-dimensional array of strings in c++?

something like that:

```
    char inCharArray[3][255];
    string outStringArray[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(inCharArray) / sizeof(inCharArray[i]); i++)
    {
        outStringArray[i] = inCharArray[i];
    }
```

Regards
Tillman

Comment: `/*const*/std::string outStringArray[3]{inCharArray[0], inCharArray[1], inCharArray[2]};`?

Comment: `/*const*/ std::vector<std::string> outStringArray(std::begin(inCharArray), std::end(inCharArray));`?

Comment: `std::copy(std::begin(inCharArray), std::end(inCharArray), std::begin(outStringArray));`?

Comment: These assume C-strings. While a C-string is always an array of characters, the inverse is not always true. OP should clarify.

Comment: are the strings in `inCharArray` null terminated? ie are they strings? or is it just an array of chars (may contain `\0` in the middle) ?

Comment: In my case the "outStringArray" is a simple null terminated c-string array.

Comment: I love how OP was asked *specifically* about `inCharArray` and answered with `outStringArray`. Classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using STL algorithm is one of the best way to do it.

```
char inCharArray[3][255];
string outStringArray[3];

std::transform(
    std::begin(inCharrArray),
    std::end(inCharArray),
    std::begin(outStringArray),
    [](char const* c_str) -> std::string {
        return std::string{c_str};
    }
);
```

This is assuming the strings are ending sooner than 255.

Answer (score 0):

This alternative to `std::transform` is more readable to me:

```cpp
std::copy(std::begin(inCharArray),
          std::end(inCharArray),
          std::begin(outStringArray));

// only safe if input strings are null-terminated and arrays have equal size
static_assert(std::size(inCharArray) == std::size(outStringArray),
              "arrays are not equal size");
```

Also consider using `std::array` instead of C-style arrays while you're writing C++ code.